# PHP - подмена изображения

Tags: php, изображения

Всем привет. Решил поинтересоваться технической фишкой, которую обнаруживаю на сайтах.
Суть такова: Предоставляется изображение в обычном формате, а при сохранение картинки производится подстановка водяного знака. Такая же фишка происходит, если изображение загрузил сам пользователь. Пример работы изображения: 1001mem.ru

Как работает такой метод? Очень интересна техническая сторона, желательно подробная. =) Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет там никакой подмены - нижняя часть картинки просто скрыта. Посмотрите в инспекторе своего браузера.

Конкретнее:

```
.post-image .image-wrap img 
{ margin: 0 auto -30px; }
```